# Export an environment variable using a make target in MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, makefile, command-line, environment-variables

Might sound like a very noob question, but what I want to do is create and set an env variable via a make target and access that env variable through other make targets.

I have tried the below and few other variations of it, but cannot figure it out.

```
.PHONY: exporttest
exporttest:
    export MY_ENV_VAR=$(shell echo "Bang")
```

One of my colleagues ran the same target on his Mac and the env variable was set.

Please advise how I can get this done/fix my Mac?

Comment: You can't do it. Each makefile recipe runs in a new process. So variables set in one process are discarded when the process ends and you execute another recipe.

Comment: Just set a makefile variable at top-level, and use that in the appropriate targets.

Comment: Actually each **line** in a recipe is run in a separate process.  So you can't even use shell variables that were set in a previous (logical) line, in a subsequent (logical) line.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I was able to set a variable with eval on one line and access it in one of the following lines. Regarding defining a makefile variable on the top, would the value persist and be shared anong other make targets?